# Why can ROC_AUC score decrease after cross-validation?

Tags: roc, k-fold

Please help, need an advice or link to some manual.
While training the model, performed these steps:

1. Choosing the model (CatBoostRegressor)
2. Tuning hyperparameters with Optuna framework

Model with *study.best_trial.params* scored 0.92

3. Used this model as an input to StratifiedKFold()

Finished with 0.95 average of 10 folds.

4. Submit...

And got 0.77 roc_auc_score on the test data.

Have I missed a step here?

Comment: How your objective function looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I should close this question (but I can't find a way to). Already got an answer, data shift takes place.